# How to get velocity of a mesh with React-Three-Cannon?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a mesh declared by using *@React-Three/Cannon*:

```
const [obstacleRef, obstacleApi] = useBox(() => ({
  mass: 1,
  position: [0, 2, -5],
}));
```

I change the velocity in `useFrame`:

```
useFrame(() => {
  obstacleApi.velocity.set(0, 0, 1);
});
```

But I need to get Y velocity to increase Z velocity in `useFrame` above.

How can I do that? I checked `obstacleRef` and `obstacleApi` and found nothing related.

**UPDATE:**
Event `obstacleApi.velocity.subscribe` method doesn't detect any change in velocity.